# Converting openssl digest signing statement to Java code

Tags: java, encryption, openssl, digital-signature, digest

I'm trying to convert an OpenSSL linux statement to Java code, but so far, I've been getting different results. It's about the following statement:

```
echo "testString" | openssl dgst -sha256 -sign private.key -passin "pass:passw0rd" | openssl base64 -A
```

This echo's the following result:

> 6FFS+Vym+Su887Mq0YG1OsURb7Csw9czvycShEd2P6SHQYKE7O6V/wzi5XTGJcP/sTaHvOAIZ5g8cIs5SEKD8NGaMLPD35hnNAn1nlAVfBT826pwIjUvzJII7d2aHKTjVfIhsyUEXbRtSMrrJNrtfyCTYYYOxCWzZv0RiOczQlpy1Jaa46fSacvaRKXi9xV/W1KxYcNS8wc/mc3Ujeqc4gfESb2YJU8yP3P269iENCjDq++8CTyEj4vm4XxlXYBIREEK7qUfxTTo1+XKfBck/0/RGwZD26jhRNHKMI6maW0mB+fRLjnYIvBqQKRbZnoIEmjy8AYy8CGC56Ujh2r3dg==

Now I'm trying the following Java code:

```
public String encryptString(byte[] data) {
    try {
        java.security.Security.addProvider(new org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider());

        Resource keyStore = ctx.getResource(keystoreLocation);
        PrivateKey privateKey = loadPrivateKey(keyStore.getInputStream());

        Signature signature = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withRSA", "BC");
        signature.initSign(privateKey);
        signature.update(data);
        String result = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(signature.sign());

        // return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(signature.sign());
        return null;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("Something went wrong during encryption.");
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

This code ends up with the encoded result which differs from the linux statement:

> uxdvp2oTaoS/Iln9KYNL+2o49fbW2Br0jIt9cc/F3xRm3XnsEVVBzKA0vL9yMCAvNvH0nfBt2nRHQzL5PtN+uLy0pKCtHBKxfgdTZjnhm0qdj6tcOIvx3f1AkrMhXAk6bfEMqxu5dEl8AJ2wvYvggyBDXn+Bv0TG+2iavNZ80RDqILExQvGSnD7O9BSPtOVtf17ahyzagYNiqEGxdqLUSZHNNs7Q10hYpeJ7cB6Jg/NRUGFS5Z14xmvjqyk63VFXw86hCvX1rnDt3vL7XRdSRKMhiI9SfnSHbNSNEMcSBRxX6nb1nkuuqjjzNBXZAduNAOBzIrrROmwQkXVOFKXDCw==

I've also tried some other things. I tried working with the Cipher implementation:

```
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/None/NoPadding", "BC");
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, privateKey);

byte[] hash = digest.digest(data);
byte[] signature = cipher.doFinal(hash);

String hashEncoded = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(hash);
String signatureEncoded = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(hash);
```

But all the String's end up shorter than expected. I also saw the 'dgst' statement so I was wondering I had to digest the message (using `MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256", "BC");`) but here I got the same problem, way shorter String's.

Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: You try to sign the string "testString". Have you checked whether the encoding you used to turn that string into the `byte[] data` Java parameter is the same as the encoding openssl applies to the string data input?

Comment: That being said, without your public key the dumps of the signatures don't help at all (other than seeing that they differ). Thus, can you share your public key?

Comment: I verified the encoding by changing some code to forcefully match the linux terminal. And thank you for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is very simple, and not particularly interesting. `echo "testString"` appends a newline to the string being echoed. For most versions of echo, the `-n` option will suppress the newline. Or, just as good, you can add the newline in the java version, say with something like:

```
signature.update("testString\n".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
```